# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError even after including the dependency in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have included a `jar` dependency in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openoces</groupId>
  <artifactId>ooapi</artifactId>
  <version>1.203.0</version>
</dependency>
```

During compilation it does not throw any error but on running the application it throw following error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openoces/ooapi/web/Signer
```

Comment: In can't find this JAR in Maven central. Do you have a link to it?

Comment: kept in local maven repository

Comment: Can you show it to us? I looks like we have to see it in order to help you.

Comment: Perhaps you only recompiled it and didn't repackage the application so the jar didn't end up in classpath.

Comment: if you use eclipse (or somewhere  similar) try to clean and rebuild the project, and after "refresh Maven dependency" into package explorer (shortcut is Shift+F5)

Comment: pom.xml doens't guarantee jars at runtime.

Comment: I am using intelij and i check jar is present in classpath